# Can you still be grouped with players you've muted?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

I try to keep my sanity in moba's by muting people early if they become unfriendly in chat. You'd expect not to be grouped again with people you've muted, but I've experienced first hand that this is *not* the case in Dota 2 (it was a very confusing bit of party chat the first few minutes of the game where I started out with someone I had previously muted...).

Long story short: **in HotS, will you be grouped with people you've previously muted?** The specific feature I'm talking about is the "Block all communications from this player" button in the <kbd>tab</kbd> screen you can get while in a game.

Comment: Good question. I suspect you can, unfortunately, otherwise description would be "Block all communications from this player and never be matched with him(-er) again". But I haven't seen this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, it is possible to be grouped with muted/blocked players; it's happened to me during several back-to-back games.

That said, in my experience, this generally only happens during times when there is a low player pool in the queue (such as playing ranked immediately before daily quests go out), so I would guess that Blizzard's queue system tries to avoid doing this -- unless it can't make an evenly matched game without doing so, since balancing for a 50-50 win chance is the matchmaking system's #1 priority.

EDIT:
Here's some further evidence of this happening, on the Heroes of the Storm forums:
http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/forum/topic/15537134741
http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/forum/topic/15700255007